# in trim function there's an if-check not working properly, why?

Tags: c, string, memory-management, trim

EDIT: I've edited my code, and this is the result:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *trim(const char *s) {
    if (s == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    size_t count_1 = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        count_1++;
    }
    if (count_1 < 1) {
        return NULL; 
    }
    size_t count_2 = 0;  
    if (isspace(s[0])) {
        count_2++;
    }
    if (isspace(s[count_1 - 1])) {
        count_2++;
    }
    size_t max_length = (count_1 - count_2) + 1u;
    if (max_length >= count_1) {
        return NULL;
    }
    char *str = malloc(max_length);
    if (!str) {
        return NULL;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isspace(s[i]) == 0) { // if isspace is false. 
            str[i] = s[i];
        }
    }
    str[count_1 - count_2] = 0;
    return str;
}

int main(void) {
    char s[] = " a b ";
    char *str;
    str = trim(s);

    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

now, the problem is here

```
    for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isspace(s[i]) == 0) { // if isspace is false. 
            str[i] = s[i];
        }
```

I have a buffer overrun, even if I've checked the length. In fact, if `count_1` is equal to zero, I have a buffer overrun error, but I've excluded this case, but the problem persists. By debugging line-by-line, I've noticed I have an undefined behavior.

---

I wanted to try to simplify the suggested solution for this exercise, therefore I've written another code for the same exercise.

this is the original answer: [trim function halve the memory size to remove the whitespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70141741/trim-function-halve-the-memory-size-to-remove-the-whitespaces)

this is the minimal reproducible code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *trim(const char *s) {
    size_t count_1 = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        count_1++;
    }
    size_t count_2 = 0;
    if (isspace(s[0])) {
        count_2++;
    }
    if (isspace(s[count_1])) {
        count_2++;
    }
    size_t max_length = (count_1 - count_2) + 1u; 
    if (max_length >= count_1) {
        return NULL; 
    }
    char *str = malloc(max_length); 
    if (!str) {
        return NULL; 
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isalpha(s[i]) == 0) { // if isalpha is false. 
            str[i] = s[i]; 
        } 
        str[count_1 - count_2] = 0; 
    }
    return str; 
}

int main(void) {
    char s[] = " a b "; 
    char *str; 
    str = trim(s);

    free(str); 
    return 0; 
}
```

here's the detailed explanation about what I've done so far:

- I've counted characters of the string `s`, and the length is stored in `count_1`.
- I've counted how many whitespaces I have at the beginning of the string, and at the end of the string; and the amount is stored in `count_2`.

note: I've chosen to use `isspace` function (in `<ctype.h>`), because I tried to type `' '` (i.e a whitespace), but the result is not correct, and these if-checks are not evaluated whatsoever. (I used the debugger line-by-line to state this thing).

- before `malloc` the memory I've used a check condition to avoid buffer overrun (it's similar to the question I asked yesterday), meaning I've allocated enough memory if and only if `max_length` is less than `count_1`. doing this way, I have no buffer overrun warning.

I think I can avoid to explain the final steps, because they are self explanatory and I also think they doesn't cause errors. If I'm wrong, I'll edit this point.

issue I have no clue how to fix it:

- by debugging line-by-line, I've noticed that when the flow of execution goes to the 2nd if-check, the `if` body is not executed whatsoever. And this is strange, because the first one works fine.

Comment: If `count_1` is the string length then `s[count_1]` is the NUL teminator. So `isspace(s[count_1])` is not looking at the last character. Also, you need to check that `count_1` is > 0 before checking the first character, and is > 1 before checking the last character (or it will be the same as the first character).

Comment: the first for-loop doesn't include the zero terminator, so I thought count_1 was the last character of the entire string. Could you explain better the second part of your comment in the answer section? (I think I've understood the first part, and I think the solution is "s[count_1-1]").

Comment: Think about it. If the string length is `0` then `s[0]` is the terminator, not the last character (there isn't any). If the length is `1` then `s[0]` is the last character and `s[1]` is the terminator. I ddin't get as far as any `for` loop, I stopped there.

Comment: I didn't get your point

Comment: why aren't there a last character? if the length is zero? the last character should be s[0] as well

Comment: My point is that `if (isspace(s[count_1]))` does not look at the final string character, it looks at the string terminator. So you have tried to test for leading and trailing whitespace to trim, but (a) you didn't check the string is *long enough* and (b) you aren't looking at the last character. That is at `s[count_1 - 1]` and now you can see the need to check the length too, i hope. For a 0-length string that will be out of bounds, and for a 1-length string it's the same as the leading character.

Comment: okay, now I think I got your point, you mean that I should type "s[count_1 -1]", and this should solve the problem. okay, I try to fix the problem

Comment: I mean what I wrote, it is quite clear. You need to check the length too.

Comment: Fyi, half the difficulty of this goes out the window if you just advance `s` up the string until one of (a) the terminator, or (b) a non-whitespace char, conditions are met. That's going to be where you want to start anyway. After doing that, if there is any meat left in the string (e.g. it wasn't all whitespace),  then the only hard part is finding the last char (which may also be the first char), computing the length, allocating, copying, terminating, and finally returning. [example here](https://godbolt.org/z/jnraW177x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `count_1` is the length of the string, you should name it more explicitly as `len`
- you return `NULL` if no trimming is needed. This is questionable. You should probably return a copy of the string in all cases and only return `NULL` in case of allocation failure.
- you only test for 1 space char at the start of the string.
- you only test for 1 space char at the end of the string.
- furthermore this space might be counted twice if the string is `" "`.
- `max_length` is a misnomer: it is not the *length* of the new string, but the allocation size, `new_size` seems more appropriate.
- in the final loop, you use the same index `i` into the original and the new string: this is incorrect. You should use a separate index so characters from the original string can be copied after skipping the initial space.
- `str[count_1 - count_2] = 0;` is redundant inside the loop: you should move this statement after the end of the loop.
- argument values of type `char` should be cast as `(unsigned char)` when passed to the functions and macros defined in `<ctype.h>` to avoid undefined behavior on negative values on platforms where the `char` type is signed. These functions are only defined for the values of type `unsigned char` (between `0` and `UCHAR_MAX`) and the special negative value `EOF`. These values are the ones returned by `getchar()` and `getc()`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *trim(const char *s) {
    if (s == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    size_t start, end;
    for (start = 0; isspace((unsigned char)s[start]); start++) {
        continue;
    }
    for (end = start; s[end] != '\0'; end++) {
        continue;
    }
    while (end > start && isspace((unsigned char)s[end - 1])) {
        end--;
    }
    // if you are allowed to use strndup, you can return the new string this way:
    //return strndup(str + start, end - start);

    char *new_str = malloc(end - start + 1);
    if (new_str) {
        size_t j = 0;  // index into the new string
        for (size_t i = start; i < end; i++) {
            new_str[j++] = str[i];
        }
        new_str[j] = '\0';
    }
    return new_str;
}

int main(void) {
    char s[] = " a b ";
    char *str = trim(s);
    printf("trim(\"%s\") -> \"%s\"\n", s, str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "for (start = 0; isspace((unsigned char)s[start]); start++) {
        continue;" why did you use a cast?

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini: I use a cast because `isspace()` is only defined for the values of type `unsigned char` and the special negative value `EOF`. `isspace(s[start])` has undefined behavior on platforms where the type `char` is signed and `s[start]` is negative.